# iOS Cocoapods issue: No such module in parts of my project (custom folder & Apple Watch target)

Tags: ios, module, cocoapods, target, swxmlhash

I have trouble installing following cocoapod correctly:
github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash

Interestingly enough, I can access the framework "SWXMLHash" installed by the pod in my regular ViewController.swift but cannot access it in my Apple Watch Extension files. Furthermore, I cannot access it in a custom group/folder I made to encapsulate the helper methods like WebServiceHelper.swift

[Overview of my folder structure (Image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlClE.png)

I can easily import and use the framework provided by the pod in my ViewController.swift **for iPhone**.
But when I try to access it **outside** the folder containing "ViewController.swift" / "AppDelegate.swift" I get following error:

> No such module 'SWXMLHash'

[Error when I try to access the framework in my "myAppName Kit"-folder (Image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyJHK.png)

My Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'SWXMLHash', '~> 2.1.0'

target 'myAppName' do

end

target 'myAppNameTests' do

end

target 'myAppNameUITests' do

end

target 'myAppName Watch' do

end

target 'myAppName Watch Extension' do

end
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

please make podfile like this

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'



target 'myAppName' do
pod 'SWXMLHash', '~> 2.1.0'
end

target 'myAppNameTests' do

end

target 'myAppNameUITests' do

end

target 'myAppName Watch' do
pod 'SWXMLHash', '~> 2.1.0'
end

target 'myAppName Watch Extension' do
pod 'SWXMLHash', '~> 2.1.0'
end
```

Comment: thanks for the tip! Unfortunately, it still shows the error in the corresponding parts.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I think your `Podfile` should look (**note** that I only specified the iOS and Watch targets for clarity, you'll need to include whichever ones are necessary with the correct platform for each):

```
use_frameworks!

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'myAppName' do
    platform :ios, '8.0'
    pod 'SWXMLHash', '~> 2.1.0'
end

# snipped...

target 'myAppName Watch' do
    platform :watchos, '2.0'
    pod 'SWXMLHash', '~> 2.1.0'    
end
```

I didn't add it for every one of them, but note that the `:platform` is specified differently for the watch target. You don't want the `ios` target at the global level.

Hope this helps.